# Understanding $Po(np)\{A\}$ probability notation

Tags: probability, notation

I am trying to read a textbook on probability and am already stuck on what must be basic notation.  It says

> Thus, for example, if $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, it follows
>   that for some $c$ not depending on $A$, $n$ or $p$, $$|\mathbb{P}[W
>  \in A] - Po(np)\{A\}| \leq c \sum_{k\in A} \frac{(np)^k}{k!}e^{-np}\{np^2+k^2n^{-1}\}$$

Po is the Poisson distribution but what exactly does $Po(np)\{A\}$  mean? I am assuming the curly brackets on the right hand side of the inequality don't have any special meaning.

Comment: Po(np) is the Poisson distribution with parameter np and Po(np)(A) is the measure of A by the distribution Po(np).

Comment: @Did Thank you. Is it possible to explain for someone who hasn't done a measure theory course (i.e. me)?  Maybe it would be easier to explain what $|\mathbb{P}[W
 \in A] - Po(np)\{A\}|$ is meant to signify.  I do have some idea what "measure" means but I don't understand " the measure of A by the distribution[...]".

Comment: How do you picture the object called "a Poisson distribution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
|\mathbb{P}[W \in A] - Po(np)\{A\}|
\end{equation}
means the difference between the probability that the random variable $W$ takes a value in the set $A$ and the probability that a Poisson random variable with mean $np$ takes its value in the set $A$.  So if we say $X \sim Po(np)$, we could re-write it as
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb{P}[W \in A] - \mathbb{P}[X \in A]|.
\end{equation}
For example, if $A = \{k\}$, where $k$ is just some positive integer, then it would be $|\mathbb{P}[W = k] - \mathbb{P}[X = k]|$, and $\mathbb{P}[X=k] = (np)^k e^{-np}/k!$.  So your inequality is basically saying how 'close' the random variable $W$ is to a random variable that follows a Poisson distribution with mean $np$, in some sense.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!